# "The call is ambiguous between the following methods" for services.AddCors()

Tags: cors, nuget, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015 Update 3.
I am busy attempting to enable CORS as per this resource:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/cors.html

- I created a new .NET Core  Web API project version 1.0.0.
- In Startup.cs, under `ConfigureServices()` I added:
  `services.AddCors()`
- However, after adding the following dependency to `project.json`:
  `"Microsoft.AspNet.Cors": "6.0.0-rc1-final"`, I got the following error:

  `The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.CorsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddCors(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)' and 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.CorsServiceCollectionExtensions.AddCors(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection)'`

I can confirm that removing that dependency resolves the error. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

So apparently I neglected to notice the conspicuous warning at the top of the page. The docs weren't yet updated for version 1.0.0.

Using `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors": "1.0.0"` resolved this problem.

Comment: I have that and no other AspNet libraries and still i get this error